# VBA - automatic timestamp triggered upon deletion of data and filter change

Tags: excel, vba

I simply would like to add an automatic time stamp on the excel.

Could you please advise on the 2 issues i ran across while using the table for bulk insertion/deletion

1, Upon Multiple row deletion the time stamp still remains there, would prefer to it to be deleted

2, Upon Multiple row Insertion/Deletion the time stamp goes into an error thanks in advance

Thanks in advance

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myTableRange As Range, TargetVal As String
Set myTableRange = Range("C2:Y1048576") 'Change to your range..
If Intersect(Target, myTableRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
.Undo
TargetVal = Target.Value
.Undo
If Target.Value <> TargetVal Then

'Your Code doing something with timestamp
Set myDateTimeRange = Range("A" & Target.Row)

'Column for last updated date/time
Set myUpdatedRange = Range("B" & Target.Row)

'Set Time Stamp Value
myDateTimeRange.Value = Format(Now)

'Column for last updated date/time
 myUpdatedRange.Value = Format(Now)

    Debug.Print Target.Value
End If
.EnableEvents = True
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: are you getting any error in the above code ? If yes then can you write in which line error pops ?